# How to list zookeeper znodes in a reliable way?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I would like to list all of my subnodes , say:  `ls /mynode`

Unfortunately the above command doesnt work when we have a massive amount of subnodes.
 The reason is the buffer limit. Even if we increase it by jute.maxbuffer we can reach that limit also.

So what can we do if we want to list all of our nodes?
1.Does Zk support paging? No.
2.Does Zk support wildcards? No.
3.Does Zk support filtering? No.

What is the solution?

Comment: There was a patch submitted [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-2260) to add pagination to getChildren() call but was never merged. I know this is not a real solution but you could add another directory level (e.g. grouping znodes by their name's first char).